# isql DECLARE statement to psql

Tags: sybase, plpgsql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL DB and have a script which calculates dates from an old Sybase DB. How can I do the same thing is PostgreSQL ?

```
isql 

DBCOMMAND="eval isql -d $DATABASE -U user -P passwd "

$DBCOMMAND << MSG > $LOG_MEM_EXCEP

DECLARE @PREVINTDATETIME DATETIME 

select @PREVINTDATETIME=(DATEADD(hh, -24, GETDATE()))

DECLARE @CURDATE DATETIME

select CURDATE=GETDATE()

select XTIME, MESSAGE from EXCEPTION_ALERTS where (XTIME between @PREVINTDATETIME AND @CURDATE)

exit MSG
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically it burns down to a simple SQL statement:

```
SELECT xtime, message
FROM   exception_alerts
WHERE  xtime BETWEEN now() - interval '1d' AND now();
```

.. returning two columns of all rows in table `exception_alerts` from the last 24 hours.

Did you want to make a sql or plpgsql function out of it? Or call it from the shell using the command line interface `psql`? What is the exact form you would expect in return? Including column names?

Comment: I'm calling it from a shell script.  We use to run this on a Sybase DB which is now a PostgreSQL DB. So I'am trying to convert to psql.

Comment: I am using DBCOMMAND="eval psql -d $DATABASE "  instead. and need to create some variables that a DATETIME type variables - so it will calculate -24 hours - I hope that makes more sense.   I want to only display the xtime and message colums, if the xtime colume is between the 2 calculated times

Comment: I did actually test your simple SQL statement and it worked a treat so I will use that - Thanks so much for your help !